# How to disable Required ip in .htacess for a sub folder

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have a website that has public_html, in it I have .htaccess that requires a specific ip.
This works great, however in the same folder there is a subfolder in the public_html, where a different website is hosted.

Therefore the required ip is also taking affect in the other website, which has it's own .htacess file which is empty.

Is there any way i can disabled the required ip for the sub-folder website, while keeping it in the main public_html ?

Thank you

Comment: Show us how exactly you made that specific IP required.

Comment: it is a simple one liner "Required [ip address]

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#satisfy `Allow from all` and `Satisfy Any` should do the trick.